# Problem with code. Using vector delete same numbers except the last entrance of it

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, iterator

The program dosen`t work but there are no errors. I need to delete numbers exept the last entry. We have 1 2 3 4 1 2 5 7 8 0 0 we need to get 3 4 1 2 5 8 8 0.

Included libraries: vector,iostream.

`

```
vector<int> MyVector = {1,2,3,4,1,2,5,7,8,0,0};
vector<int>::iterator it;


for (int i = MyVector.size() - 1; i > 0; ++i)
{

  int x = MyVector.at(i);

    for ( it = MyVector.end() - 1; it >= MyVector.begin(); it--)
    {
        if (*it == x)
        {
           MyVector.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it != MyVector.begin()
Note that you are modifying your vector while looping over it... int i is initialized only once in the first for loop... Also, I do not understand your question.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: Hint: the fact that code compiles without errors or warnings does not mean that it will produce results that you think it should.

Comment: i dont understand what you want to do. if you erase all but the last entry from 1 2 2 3 1 3 2 you should get 2 not 1 3 2

Comment: Your example's vector contents are `1,2,3,4,1,2,5,7,8,0,0`, but you talk about `1 2 2 3 1 3 2`. Which is it?

Comment: do you want to turn the vector into a set? ie remove duplicates and sort it ?

Comment: Your code is Undefined behavior, as well explained in comments and answer. However (OT), I cannot really understand why you want to implement this algorithm like that. What you want to achieve at the end is: "remove duplicates" - You can do it in O(N) under a particular hypothesis.

Comment: @Anton "We have 1 2 3 4 1 2 5 7 8 0 0 we need to get 3 4 1 2 5 8 8 0" And why is 7 absent in the result vector?.

Comment: Can you modify the vector (i.e. [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) it)? Then do that, and use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) to remove consecutive duplicates.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Not to mention why is there an extra `8` added? Probably a typo though (one of the `8` should be a `7`).

Comment: Anton, please provide more and clearer information about what you are trying to accomplish, the result you expect, and the result you're getting. An update of your question would really help us help you. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: _"I need to delete numbers exept the last entry."_ Be more clear about this please. There is no indication of how you intend to get your expected result. Take more care.

Comment: Have you tried debugging so far? What did you find out?

Answer (score 3):

From [this `erase` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> Invalidates iterators and references **at** or after the point of the erase

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

That means the iterator you pass to `erase` will itself be invalidated, and it can no longer be used. You need to use the iterator that `erase` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase#Return_value):

```
it = MyVector.erase(it);
```

Comment: I wrote as u said , it =MyVector.erase(it); But now i have an error -  Expression: can`t decremet vector iterator before begin

Comment: erase returns an iterator pointing to the next element after the one that was erased, but OP is (manually) iterating backwards

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Not a problem. Lets say the vector is `10, 11, 12` and `it` is "pointing" to the `11` element. Erasing that and assigning the result back to `it` will make `it` "point" to the element `12`. Then `it` is decreased and points to the element `10`.

Answer (score 2):

For starters this loop

```
for (int i = MyVector.size() - 1; i > 0; ++i)
                                         ^^^
```

does not make sense. At least you should write

```
for (int i = MyVector.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
                                         ^^^
```

After using the method `erase` current iterator `it` becames invalid.

You could use reverse iterators and the standard algorithm `std::find`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( auto it = std::rbegin( v ); it != std::rend( v );  )
    {
        if ( std::find( it.base(), std::end( v ), *it ) != std::end( v ) )
        {
            it = std::reverse_iterator( v.erase( std::prev( it.base() ) ) );
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 5 7 8 0 0 
3 4 1 2 5 7 8 0
```

I think that it is the result you are going to obtain.

You could write a general algorithm for such a task. For example

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator remove_duplicates( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        last = std::remove( std::next( first ), last, *first );
    }

    return last;
}
```

and call it with reverse iterators of the vector.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator remove_duplicates( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        last = std::remove( std::next( first ), last, *first );
    }

    return last;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    v.erase( remove_duplicates( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) ), std::end( v ) );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    v.assign( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    v.erase( std::begin( v ), remove_duplicates( std::rbegin( v ), std::rend( v ) ).base() );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1
```

At first there is shown how to remove duplicates values except first entries. And then there is shown how to remove duplicates values except last entries.

Answer (score 1):

From your code I understand that you want to remove duplicates from the vector. There are many ways to do that, for example you can create a `std::set` via

```
std::set my_set(my_vector.begin(),my_vector.end());
```

The set will contain no duplicates, ie basically the same elements you want to keep in the vector.
From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set)

> Range constructor. Constructs the container with the contents of the
>   range [first, last). If multiple elements in the range have keys that
>   compare equivalent, it is unspecified which element is inserted
>   (pending LWG2844).

If you need it you could turn the `set` back into a `vector`, though a container that does not conain duplicates and is sorted is a set anyhow. If you dont need the result sorted, you can use `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: i am not able to use set :c

Comment: @Anton why not?

Comment: @Anton this is something you should mention in the question. what else? `<algorithm>` is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

`erase` invalidates iterators at or after the removed position. Here's one way to make it work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> MyVector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0 };

    auto beg{ MyVector.begin() };
    for (auto it{ MyVector.rbegin() }, rend{ MyVector.rend() }; it != rend; /* empty */)
    {
        it = std::reverse_iterator(std::remove(beg, std::next(it).base(), *it));
    }
    MyVector.erase(std::unique(beg, MyVector.end()), MyVector.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You algorithm has a large complexity: O(N^2) to detect the duplicates, plus complexity for erasing the elements. It may be O(N^3) in the worst case.

The other answers indicate how to get a good result with std::vector and with correction of the iterator, but do not the address the complexity issue

This answer provides a O(nlogn) method, using std::vector.

Method :

```
1. sort indices according to array values
2. detect positions where to erase
3. build a new vector with kept values
```

An important point is that a stable sort is used, to be sure keeping the last duplicate only.

Programme:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

//  1. sort indices according to array values
//  2. detect positions where to erase
//  3. build a new vector with kept values

std::vector<int> remove_duplicate (const std::vector<int>& x) {
    std::vector<int> index (x.size());
    std::iota (index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
    std::stable_sort (index.begin(), index.end(), [&] (int i, int j) {return x[i] < x[j];});

    std::vector<bool> erase (x.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size() - 1; ++i) {
        erase[index[i]] = x[index[i]] == x[index[i+1]];
    }
    erase[index[x.size()-1]] = false;

    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (!erase[i]) result.push_back(x[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> MyVector = {1,2,3,4,1,2,5,7,8,0,0};
    auto result = remove_duplicate (MyVector);

    for (auto i: result) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```